# Where can I access the installed Maya Bonus Tools?

Tags: maya

I installed Maya 2013 Bonus Tools... checked plugin manager... don't know what plugin to load to use UV Align feature.

Where can I access the installed Bonus Tools?

Comment: Did you try the resources page? http://area.autodesk.com/blogs/stevenr/bonustools

Comment: Yeah, you're right! Didn't mention it somehow.

Comment: No need to update the question with "Solved" users can see from the answer section that there's a solution. You can accept your answer when you're able.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Bonus Tools](http://area.autodesk.com/blogs/stevenr/bonustools) page:

> If you have installed Bonus Tools but can not see the menu then you
>   may need to update your userSetup file. See below...
>
> Copy C:\Program
>   Files\Autodesk\MayaBonusTools2012\scripts\userSetup.mel Copy
>   C:\Program Files\Autodesk\MayaBonusTools2012\python\userSetup.py
>
> Paste both in C:\users\name\My Documents\maya12-x64\prefs\scripts

Also don't forget to run `userSetup.mel` script from Maya.